# removing lines between two patterns (not inclusive) with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Ok

I know that this is trivial question but: How can i remove lines from files that are between two known patterns/words:

> pattern1
>   garbage
>   pattern2

to obtain:

> pattern1
>   pattern2

And does anyone known good(simple written!) resources for studying sed?? With many clear examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287755/608639), [SED delete lines between two pattern matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8085633/608639), [sed delete lines between two patterns, without the second pattern, including the first pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42898905/608639), [SED delete specific lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19233578/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sed -n '/pattern1/{p; :a; N; /pattern2/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p' inputfile
```

Explanation:

```
/pattern1/{         # if pattern1 is found
    p               # print it
    :a              # loop
        N           # and accumulate lines
    /pattern2/!ba   # until pattern2 is found
    s/.*\n//        # delete the part before pattern2
}
p                   # print the line (it's either pattern2 or it's outside the block)
```

**Edit:**

Some versions of `sed` have to be spoon-fed:

```
sed -n -e '/pattern1/{' -e 'p' -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '/pattern2/!ba' -e 's/.*\n//' -e '}' -e 'p' inputfile
```

Comment: it gives me `sed: -e expression #1, char 58: Unknown option to 's'`. My sed version is 3.02

Comment: @Dennis: Oh, version from edit is doing the right thing. Thanks once more !

Comment: Or with less black magic `sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern1/b;/pattern2/b;d}' inputfile` :)

Comment: @pooh: Your first one doesn't work with this test data (lines with "xxx" should not be printed, everything else should): `echo -e 'aaa\npattern1\ncccxxx\ndddxxx \npattern2\nfff\nggg\npattern1\nAAAxxx\nBBBxxx \nCCCxxx\nDDDxxx\npattern2\nEEE\nFFF'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Ah, true:) Tested on one line contents!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I tried your test data with pooh's suggestion and it worked fine (on OSX, maybe that's why?). Why does it fail, or why should it?

Comment: @jakesandlund: pooh's `sed` command in the comment from Feb 22 '11 at 13:23 *does* work with my test data from my comment from Feb 22 '11 at 14:38. You'll note that my comment refers to "[pooh's] first one". There is only one at this point, and I can't remember if there was another that may now be deleted, but that phrase would seem to imply so. Pooh's leading "Or" would seem to also imply that (or it could refer to the "black magic" in my answer). In any case, pooh's extant version is perfectly fine and is quite a bit more straightforward than mine.

Comment: Any of those solution does work when pattern1==pattern2 but solution proposed by user332325 works in that case

Answer (score 17):

This will work for both GNU and BSD sed:

```
sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{//!d;}' file
```

Comment: If anybody else uses this with BSD `sed` (i.e. Mac OSX), and you get an error `extra characters at the end of d command`, simply add `;` after the `d` like this:
`sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{//!d;}' file`

Comment: how do you do this inclusive of the patterns?

Answer (score 5):

This is easily done with awk:

```
BEGIN { doPrint = 1; }
/pattern1/ { doPrint = 0; print $0; }
/pattern2/ { doPrint = 1; }
{ if (doPrint) print $0; }
```

I've found the [sed info](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is fairly easy reading, with many examples.  Same thing for [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/pattern1/{g=1;next}/pattern2/{g=0;next}g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

This sed code will work as well:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/d' FILE
```

Comment: Although not as OP wanted, this works well as the *inclusive* version of the answer by @potong

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Unix text editor ed:

```
echo '
pattern1
garbage
pattern2
' > test.txt

cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s test.txt &>/dev/null
  H
  /pattern1/+1,/pattern2/-1d
  wq
EOF
```

For more information see: [Editing files with the ed text editor from scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed)