# SED delete lines between two pattern matches

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace lines between two pattern/string matches using SED see below. I need to delete lines below `interface GigabitEthernet0/3` up to `interface GigabitEthernet0/4`, but leaving both interface names.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 duplex full
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 mls qos trust dscp
!
```

outcome:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 duplex full
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 mls qos trust dscp
!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287755/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Income:

```
$> cat ./text 
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 duplex full
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 mls qos trust dscp
!
```

Outcome:

```
$> cat ./text | sed '/interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/,/\!/c interface GigabitEthernet0\/3\n!'
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 duplex full
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 mls qos trust dscp
!
```

Sed can work with [multi-line patterns](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-47). We just use `c` command which is changing matched pattern (from `interface GigabitEthernet0/3` to `!`) with `interface GigabitEthernet0/3` and `!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test
1
start
2
end
3
$ sed -n '1,/start/p;/end/,$p' test
1
start
end
3
$ sed '/start/,/end/d' test
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '\#^interface GigabitEthernet0/3#,/^!/{//!d}' input_file
```

or as you described it in the question:

```
sed -e '\#^interface GigabitEthernet0/3#,\#^interface GigabitEthernet0/4#{//!d;/4/s/^/!\n/}' input_file
```

presuming you want to preserve the `!` on the line prior to the second interface. If you don't want the `!` then omit `/4/s/^/!\n/` from the last bit of the sed command

Answer (score 0):

after posting I found my answer: here's my solution

```
cat somerouter.config | sed '/interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/,/interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/{/^interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/p;d;}' somerouter.config > somenewerrouter.config
```

Then I just add back interface 0/3 with

```
sed -e '/interface\ GigabitEthernet0\/4/ i\
interface\ GigabitEthernet0\/3\
 description\ NOT USED\
 shutdown\
!' $filesw.tmp.1 > $filesw.tmp.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer seems simple to me:

```
sed -e "/interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/p" \
    -e "/interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/p" \
    -e "/interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/,/interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/d" "$@"
```

Print lines matching 'interface GigabitEthernet0/3', and lines containing 'interface GigabitEthernet0/4'; delete the lines between and including the two.

The only possible issue is that if there is 'interface GigabitEthernet0/4' and no preceding 'interface GigabitEthernet0/3', then that line will be doubled up.  If that's an actual problem, then go for a more complex script:

```
sed -e "/interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/,/interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/{
        /interface GigabitEthernet0\/3/p
        /interface GigabitEthernet0\/4/p
        d
        }" "$@"
```

If you're adamant it must be one line, use semicolons, but the result is illegible.