# How to delete string between two HTML tags in one row using bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I have been working on some simple `bash` script recently, which parses specific data from webpages. I have used `tr '\r\n' ' ' <file1.txt >file2.txt` to make sure, all extracted data from page is stored in `file1.txt` in one row. So then I need to match all strings between `<th>...</th>` tags in this line and delete them or replace with `' '` sign.
So here is some expamle code:

```
    <td>Abaktal hm</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Package</th> <td>flm 10x400 mg</td> <th>Indesit</th>
```

I have used `sed` and tried something like

```
    sed -i 's/\<th\>.*?\<\/th\>/ /g' output.txt
```

But it didn't work. I think problem is in `?` sign. It works with `?` sign in regular expressions, but probably not in `bash`.

Comment: It's a bad idea to parse html with shell.

Comment: You're using a unix variant, use one of the many languages available, such as perl, python, ruby, etc. to parse that.

Comment: I know that this is not the ideal solution, but solving this task is the key to finish what I am working on. So is there some form of e.g. `sed` command to solve this problem? Just need to select all those strings at once.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with sputnick and others, the answer to your immediate question would be:

```
sed -ir 's/<th>[^<]+<\/th>//g'
```

This works on your sample data just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt seems definitely wrong.

You can't realistically parse tag-based markup languages like `HTML` and `XML` using `Bash` or utilities such as `grep`, `sed` or `cut`. If you just want to dump/render `HTML`, see `(links|links2|lynx|w3m) -dump`, `html2text`, `vilistextum`. For parsing out pieces of data, see `tidy+(xmlstarlet|xmllint|xmlgawk|xpath|xml2)`, or learn `xslt`.

See

- https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td>
     Abaktal hm
 </td>
 <th>
     Package
 </th> 
 <td>
     flm 10x400 mg</td>
 <th> 
     Indesit
 </th>
```

If you have this type of input the below command will work

sed -n '//{p; :a; N; /</th>/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p' output.txt

It will delete the content between

```
 <th>...</th> tags
```

For more info 
[removing lines between two patterns (not inclusive) with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071901/removing-lines-between-two-patterns-not-inclusive-with-sed)