# SED delete specific lines between two patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, sed, icalendar

I am trying to filter an `*.ics` file using `sed`. The `*.ics` file looks like this:

```
[...]

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:0xfoo
SUMMARY:foo
DTSTART:20131212T090000
DTEND:20131212T100000
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20131212T100000
LOCATION:foo
CATEGORIES:foo
DESCRIPTION:foo
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT

[...]
```

I want to delete lines starting e.g. with `UID` or `SEQUENCE`, but only if they are **between** `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT`

I tried to delete these lines with:

```
sed '/^BEGIN:VEVENT/,/^END:VEVENT/ /^UID/d'
```

But it will only return an error saying something like `unknown command '/'`

How is it possible to delete these lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this line:

```
 sed '/^BEGIN:VEVENT/,/^END:VEVENT/{/^\(UID\|SEQUENCE\)/d}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk:

```
awk '
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ { inBlock = 1 }
inBlock {
    if ( /END:VEVENT/ ) {
        inBlock = 0
    }
    else if ( /^(UID|SEQUENCE)/ ) {
        next
    }
}
{ print }
' file
```

Pseudo-code explanation (`inBlock` is a boolean variable, and `line` is just an imaginary string variable):

```
WHILE read line from file DO

    IF ( line contains the regexp "BEGIN:VEVENT" ) THEN
        inBlock = TRUE

    ENDIF

    IF ( inBlock == TRUE ) THEN

        IF ( line contains the regexp "END:VEVENT" ) THEN
            inBlock = FALSE

        ELSIF ( line starts with the regexp "UID" or "SEQUENCE" ) THEN
            do no further processing on this line

        ENDIF

    ENDIF

    print the current line

ENDWHILE
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I haven't used awk a lot before, so I don't really understand what it is doing here. I will look into it, when I've got time!

Comment: I added a pseudo-code explanation in case that helps. Just remember that awk reads lines using a builtin while-not-eof loop, and that each statement in an awk script is made up of `<condition> { <action> }` segments (where the action is executed if the condition is tue) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk '/^BEGIN:VEVENT/,/^END:VEVENT/ {if ($0~/^UID|^SEQUENCE/) next}1' file
```

If line starts with `UID` or `SEQUENCE` in the block section from `BEGIN:VEVENT` to `END:VEVENT`, just skip the line