# Delete text between 2 patterns using sed

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed, command

I'm trying to remove some JavaScript between two patterns. The patterns are:

```
/* React App Start */
```

And

```
/* React App End */
```

I can successfully remove the JavaScript with the following:

```
sed -i -e '/\/\* React App Start \*\//,/\/\* React App End \*\//d' views/layouts/index.html
```

However, this also removes the patterns which I do not want. Therefore, I tried the following, but it only removes some of the JavaScript:

```
sed -i -e '/\/\* React App Start \*\//,/\/\* React App End \*\//{//!d;}' views/layouts/index.hml
```

Can anyone help please? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: See: [removing lines between two patterns (not inclusive) with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5071901/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I looked that that page.. had no luck with `sed -n -e '/\/\* React App Start \*\//{' -e 'p' -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '/\/\* React App End \*\//!ba' -e 's/.*\n//' -e '}' -e 'p' views/layouts/index.html`

Comment: OK, so it runs when i install gsed. However, it still doesn't remove the following which is between the two patterns. `    animation-timing-function: ${0};
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: 200ms;
  }
`),ea.rippleVisible,la,550,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, I had to enter a new line before the last pattern.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck using `ed` than `sed` for this (Assuming Macs come with it); since it was designed from the start for editing files instead of streams of text like `sed`, it lets you do things like seek backwards from an address, which is handy here:

```bash
printf "%s\n" '/React App Start/+1,/React App End/-1d' w | ed -s views/layouts/index.html
```

will **d**elete files in the range one line after the line matching the first pattern to one line before the line matching the second pattern, and then **w**rite the modified file back to disk.

Comment: That works for plain text - but not for removing JavaScript. Any idea on how to adapt it to strip all JavaScript?

Comment: @RobH Javascript in a html file *is* plain text.

Comment: Its only removing half of the Javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

Command grouping...

```
sed -iE '/\/\* React App Start \*\//,/\/\* React App End \*\//{ 
  /[/][*] React App [StarEnd]+ [*][/]/n;
  d;
}' views/layouts/index.html
```